# Change in dateformat while inserting from 1 table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables: table 1 and table 2.

One of the columns is the `date` column in table 1, which contains data like:

```
01/07/2016 00:23:45
```

I am pulling data from the 1st table to the 2nd table, but the challenge for me is that I am trying to insert this value into 2nd table as:

```
  07/01/2016 12:23:45 AM
```

Or at least like:

```
07/01/2016 00:23:45
```

Can someone please help me. How can I do this in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: looks like you are using varchar data type to store date-time, right?

Comment: If it's a date then the format is (and should be) irrelevant. It's just a display issue. If you've stored the dates as strings (`VARCHAR`) then that was a big mistake, and this is just the start of problems that you're likely to see. Since you didn't provide table structures though, there's no way to know.

Comment: @FLICKER: The data is getting loaded through ETL by clients. i don't have any access to it. based on the where condition i am loading data to other table where i need to change the format of date.

Comment: what version of sql are you using?

Comment: @TomH: the dates were stored as DATETIME2: and file of text delimited format get loaded using import-export wizard.

Comment: Please google and learn about the CONVERT() function in TSQL and all the available formats.

Comment: @FLICKER: sql server 2008

Comment: @TabAlleman: thanks... convert is the key... i got it. will it possible to convert time part too using convert? please suggest

Comment: Date formatting is a **DISPLAY LAYER PROBLEM** you should not be trying to format dates in the database. Choose proper datatypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have second in your values you can use below conversion

```
declare @dt varchar(100) = '01/07/2016 17:23:45'

select LEFT(@dt, 10) + ' ' + replace(right(CONVERT(varchar, cast(@dt as datetime), 109), 13), ':000', ' ')
```

it will result this

```
01/07/2016 5:23:45 PM
```

and for this data '01/07/2016 07:23:45'

will result

```
01/07/2016 7:23:45 AM
```

I did not find any straight way using CONVERT function